# Calling a callback method from -drawRewct: using CoreGraphics

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, core-graphics, objective-c++

I have been provided with a method used for styling, called [in / from] the  *-drawRect:* method of my UIView subclass.  Unfamiliar with lower-level CG syntax I am not sure how to call a method starting with:

```
void DrawInsetBeveledRoundedRect( CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CGFloat radius, UIColor *fillColor) {}
```

from  *-drawRect:* .

Could anybody please advise and or provide me with a steer?

Comment: how to call a C function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    DrawInsetBeveledRoundedRect(ctx, rect, 1234, [UIColor greenColor]);
}
```

Comment: Amazing - thank you so much!  I have learnt something today. Very kind.